Display two name from other table sql where id equal
I have Table called TownCity ,and Table called TicketDetails i want to display town name for source and destination where customerId=1 the problem is when sourceId=1 and destination=1 it work ,but if sourceId=1 and destination=2 it doesn't work
here is my query
SELECT        TicketDetails.tik_source, TicketDetails.tik_destination, 
         TownCity.town_name AS source, 
         TownCity.town_name AS destination,
         TicketDetails.Cust_Id
     FROM            TicketDetails INNER JOIN
                     TownCity ON TicketDetails.tik_destination = TownCity.town_Id
                      AND TicketDetails.tik_source = TownCity.town_Id
           WHERE        (TicketDetails.Cust_Id = 1)




and this work if ids 1,1 

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

I assume you don't have a town with the value of 2, so you get no results. Without consumable sample data and expected results, we can only guess why your attempt isn't working.

It's not clear what you are asking, can you provide sample data and expected result, but not as an image

@ThomA i have uploaded town city table

@GuidoG my question when tik_source=1 and tik_destination=2 it doesn't work else if 1,1 it work

"i have uploaded town city table" I don't see any data in your question still. Just a paragraph and some code (images don't count).

@ThomA results in third image and fourth  image

I tried copying your image into SSMS, @waleed , so that I could run your query. It didn't work; images aren't text, they're images... As I stated: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

I'm on a laptop with a tiny screen. I can't read the image text.

The problem is that you have:
ON TicketDetails.tik_destination = TownCity.town_Id
AND TicketDetails.tik_source = TownCity.town_Id

this means same city must match both source and destination. What you need is to make two joins against TownCity, something like below pseudo-code:
select *
from ticketDetails t
inner join TownCity s
 ON s.town_id = t.tik_source
inner join TownCity d
 ON d.town_id = t.tik_destination

